# Enable Adobe option through Programmatically

Tags: javascript, java, jquery, adobe, pdfbox

In PDF using Adobe Reader when I am adding any comment 
through comment section, So on comment section 
it will show some default name but I need to use system 
login user name in that comment sections through programmatically
using PDFBox,Java,JavaScript.

I found one manually solutions in any PDF 
GO TO Menus
Edit >> Preferences.
Inside Preferences first options Commenting 
Check the check box Always use Log-in Name for Author name 
but it a manually process.

[image]

Please suggest How can we check the check box through 
Programmatically using PDFBox, Java, JavaScript.

Comment: Using PDF Box -
Got Solution we need to add popup properties for it so comment Popup appears. PDAnnotation.createAnnotation(dictAnnot.getDictionaryObject("Popup")).